# Wordpress tables/search functionality

Tags: wordpress

I am putting together a new website on wordpress and I am wondering what the best method is to achieve what I want.

Essentially I am wanting to have a database website that has information on each page contained in tables that have each cell of the table as a clickable link to another page.

I would also like to be able to have a search function on the site that will return results from within the tables.

A fantastic example of something similar to the functions I am trying to achieve is www.footballbootsdb.com.

Comment: There are many plugins to do what you want. Try jQuery dataTables. Integrating it shouldn't be much of a problem. Which type of WordPress setup are you using? I mean self hosted (org) or WordPress.com?

Comment: Self hosted. Does jQuery dataTables allow for import of csv files?

Comment: Try Googling for the exact same problem. I could see a lot of plugins available for what you're trying, however you'll have do a little bit of coding to adapt it for your setup.